# Get batches of 10, starting at and including a certain number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action in a controller where I want to generate a batch of 10 consecutive days for each request.

I keep track of where we are in the batch cycle by passing a variable `page`, for each batch.

The cycle of batches should start with today.

How can I express this in the simplest way?

Right now I have the following mess, which doesn't even work (each batch, except for the first one, start one day too early):

```
@page_number = (params[:page_number] || 0).to_i + 1
today        = Date.today
batch_amount = 10
first_day_of_current_batch = today + (batch_amount * (@page_number - 1))
days         = first_day_of_current_batch..(first_day_of_current_batch + batch_amount)
```

Comment: The paging starts at 0 or 1?

Comment: It doesn't matter, `page` is only a label for the batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I didn't understand completely all your requirements, so I will make a few assumptions:

- Pages start with `1`, `nil` is assumed as `1`
- Today is 27th of October, assuming that **batch size is 10 and page number 1**, the batch should be `Sun, 27 Oct 2013..Wed, 05 Nov 2013`
- Today is 27th of October, assuming that **batch size is 10 and page number 2**, the batch should be `Sun, 06 Oct 2013..Wed, 15 Nov 2013`

As You have quite a complex logic there, it will be wise to extract it to separate object.
It's considered a common and good practice, as it decouples Your code and tests.
Custom class:

```
# app/services/batch_of_days.rb
class Services::BatchOfDays
  class << self
    def create(page_nr = 1, batch_size = 10, start_from = Date.today)
      new(page_nr.to_i, batch_size, start_from).create
    end
  end

  def initialize(page_nr, batch_size, start_from)
    @page_nr    = page_nr
    @batch_size = batch_size
    @start_from = start_from
  end

  def create
    first_day..last_day
  end

private
  def first_day
    @first_day ||= @start_from + ( @page_nr - 1 ) * @batch_size
  end

  def last_day
    first_day + @batch_size - 1
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
irb(main):262:0> BatchOfDays.create
# => Sun, 27 Oct 2013..Tue, 05 Nov 2013
irb(main):262:0> BatchOfDays.create(1)
# => Sun, 27 Oct 2013..Tue, 05 Nov 2013
irb(main):263:0> BatchOfDays.create(2)
# => Wed, 06 Nov 2013..Fri, 15 Nov 2013
irb(main):264:0> BatchOfDays.create(3)
# => Sat, 16 Nov 2013..Mon, 25 Nov 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend numbering your pages starting at `0` (i.e. page #0, the first one, begins at `Date.today`).
You could then use the following:

```
@page_number = (params[:page_number] || 0).to_i
batch_amount = 10
first = (@page_number * batch_amount).days.from_now.to_date
last  = ((@page_number + 1) * batch_amount - 1).days.from_now.to_date
days = (first..last).to_a
```

the `to_date` let you specify the range as a range of consecutive days, and the `to_a` converts the range into an `Array` of `Date` objects, one for each day.